# Shiny: How to set two widgets without space

Tags: r, shiny

I have tried to set the distance between two widgets, offset= 0 in column() doesn't work. Can anyone please help me on this, I have stuck here for many hours! Thank you!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(4,
  fluidRow(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(type="text/css", "label{ display: table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; } .form-group { display: table-row;}")
    ),

    textInput(inputId = "txtInp", label = "Label = ")
  )),
  column(4,
  fluidRow(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(type="text/css", "label{ display: table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; } .form-group { display: table-row;}")
    ),
    numericInput(inputId = "numInp", label = "X", value = 0)
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output){}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: 3rd line of your code: `column(4,`. Try to change `4` to some smaller value.

Comment: @PawełChabros , it works! truly appreciate for your help!